# Python ImportError: No module sleep found

Tags: python, importerror

Need help help, just learning Python, following Raspberry project.
 Have this, as root in /etc/init.d:

```
#! /bin/bash
modprobe snd_bcm2835
amixer cset numid=3 1
python /home/pi/radio.py
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin env python
import time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
# I found loads of BBC Radio streams from http://bbcstreams.com/
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23 , GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24 , GPIO.IN)
while True:
    if GPIO.input(23)==1:
    os.system(‘sudo killall mplayer’)
    os.system(‘mplayer -playlist http://bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r1.asx   &’)
if GPIO.input(24)==1:
    os.system(‘sudo killall mplayer’)
    os.system(‘mplayer -playlist http://bbc.co.uk/radio/listen/live/r6.asx &’)
sleep(0.1);
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Making it executable:

```
chmod 755 radio
```

I reboot and get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named sleep
```

It passes import time but gets stuck on import sleep

Comment: `from time import sleep` not `import .. import ...`

Answer (score 5):

You imported `time`'s built-in function `sleep` in wrong way, `from` keyword was missing.
 It should be like this :

```
from time import sleep
```

Instead of :

```
import time import sleep
```

[This](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just change this line

```
import time import sleep
```

to

```
from time import sleep
```

your code will start working.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned , use `from time import sleep` to use directly or use `time.sleep()` in appropriate place of your code.

E.g

```
from time import sleep
sleep(1)  # sleep for a second

#  OR 

import time
time.sleep(1)  # sleep for a second
```

Answer (score 0):

`import time import sleep` => `from time import sleep`